# Display nodes with the same parent node

Tags: 8, views

Let's say I have a **Region** content type that have multiple entity reference to a **City** content Type.

When I'm on a **City page**, I would like to display **Cities** of the same **Region** as the **City page**.

How can I achieve this through a view?

Keeping in mind that I also need to display cities of a Region at some point, switching the relation owner (City having the entity reference field to Region) might no be a solution here.

Comment: Can't you just run your own query?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I'd probably use a Region reference on the City so that you only need a single-value field, but this should be quickly accomplished in Views either way.

Assuming a City reference on the Region:

1. Create a View of Content entities of type City with a Block Display.
2. Add a Node ID Contextual Filter with Default Actions set to Provide Default Value > Content ID from URL.
3. Add a required Relationship to Region/Content using your reference field.
4. Add your reference Field to the display using the Relationship and uncheck/disable Multiple Field Settings > Display all values in the same row.
5. Add a Contextual Filter for your reference field using the Relationship with Default Actions set to Provide Default Value > Content ID from URL. Then check/enable the More > Exclude option.

Now just place the block in a theme region on your site so that it shows up on the City page. #1-4 should get a View showing all Cities that share a Region with the current one. #5 should remove the current one from the results.